# Using Ant from Scala

Tags: scala

Is there something like AntBuilder from Groovy in Scala?
See:
1. [Using Ant from Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy)
2. [groovy.util.AntBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/AntBuilder.html)

**We need to execute a lot of Ant targets from several build.xml files in our deployment scripts.**
Now we are calling these ant targets from Unix shell scripts and process output from these tasks by awk+sed...
We decided to rewrite these scripts on Groovy.
But if there is the same ability in Scala I would prefer to use Scala instead of Groovy.

**UPDATE:**
It turns out that in order to start Scala script I need to have scala-compiler.jar and scala-library.jar in classpath.
It is +20MB to our distributive.
In case of Groovy we should add only groovy-all-1.8.4.jar - 6MB.

Answer (score 0):

you can try https://github.com/weihsiu/antelese, an ant dsl in scala.  disclaimer: i wrote it but haven't been maintaining it.  but i think the basic idea is a sound one if you like to take it further.